# Aspose.Cells NuGet 18.3 Worksheet object seems to to have different API for .Net Core

Tags: c#, excel, nuget-package, worksheet, aspose-cells

Until now we used the Aspose.Cells dll (.Net c#) version 17.1, now me changed to Aspose.Cells Nuget package 18.3 and converted to .net core and It seems that the Worksheet class doesn't support many features. e.g. Looks like these ones don't exist anymore:

```
Worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable
Worksheet.AutoFitColumns
Worksheet.Pictures
Worksheet.Shapes
```

And many more...
How should I use it now?
I couldn't find any documentation regarding these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this link:
[Aspose.Cells 18.2 undocumented breaking changes](https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-cells-18-2-undocumented-breaking-changes/173486)

Some of the features are missing in .NET Core and only will be available in later versions